# Disable Dynamic href Button (using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have buttons (href links) that are created dynamically based on the data fetched from the database, so the same button template is reused every time (*n times* for n users). Clicking on the button takes the user to a new page and then I want that particular button to be disabled after the user has clicked (even if he revisits the page or refreshes the page).

Can't use any method that makes use of the **id tag**.

Edit: Need not be strictly using JavaScript

Comment: You could use localStorage to remember what buttons the user has clicked, and disable them based on that?

Comment: each page is shown in a separate tab or window?

Comment: clicking on the button takes you to a new page in the same tab @repzero

Comment: would like to know how to do that @shadow

Comment: IF IT CAN"T BE ACHIEVED USING JAVASCRIPT, I'M OPEN TO OTHER METHODS TOO (if they are not that complicated)

Comment: Can you generate a hash (md5) of the url and use it as id?

Comment: if it helps I'm using php, so I'm sending data (php variable) inside href tag to determine the user for which the buttons was clicked, so the URL is unique as I'm passing php variable as data in the URL @SergioRodrigues

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but could you set a flag in the DB for the specific user once they click the link. Then just query the flag for the current user on page load and disable the link based on the flag?

Answer (score 0):

You've very limited capabilities to do this using JavaScript only (and without `id` tag). The only way I see here is to depend on other attributes of button (maybe string inside?) or order, but you said they're generated dynamically so this is not a solution. Also if you want to preserve hidden buttons between session you have to use localStorage or/and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Typically

Disabling a html button

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;
```

Enabling a html button

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;
```

Basically creating this;

```
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

But you cant use an id tag because?...

Are you able to use variables?
have your code create this dynamically, maybe using php?

put this in a js file

```
var Clickable = true
```

and html this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/main.js"></script>
if (Clickable === true){
echo "<button type='button' href='' onclick= 'Clickable = false'>Click Me!</button>";
}
else if (Clickable === false){
echo "<button type='button' href='' disabled>Click Me!</button>";
}
```

or something like this...would that work?